Clickhose error on joining with pointInPoligon
I need to handle data in tables using mat view.
CREATE TABLE test.zone
(
    `id` UInt32,
    `district` String,
    `city` String,
    `polygon` Polygon
)
ENGINE = Memory;

CREATE TABLE test.source1
(
    id UInt32,
    point Point
)
ENGINE = Null;

CREATE TABLE test.by_zone1
(
    `id` UInt32,
    `zone_id` UInt32,
    `count` UInt32
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (zone_id, id);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.mv_by_zone
TO test.by_zone1
AS SELECT
    z.id AS zone_id,
    s.id AS id,
    count(s.id) AS count
FROM test.`source1` s 
JOIN test.`zone` z ON pointInPolygon(s.point, z.polygon) 
GROUP BY z.id, s.id;

For materialized view I got this error
SQL Error [403] [07000]: Code: 403. DB::Exception: JOIN  test.source1 AS __table1 
ALL INNER JOIN test.zone AS __table2 ON pointInPolygon(__table1.point, __table2.polygon) 
join expression contains column from left and right table, you may try experimental support 
of this feature by `SET allow_experimental_join_condition = 1`. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION) 
(version 24.5.1.1065 (official build))

Am I right that I can't use pointInPolygon in this case or there is some mistake in query?

You can get this to work if you pass the setting allow_experimental_join_condition=1 in the query of the materialized view. How large is by_zone1 though? Id recommend using a polygon dictionary if possible here. This has an example https://clickhouse.com/blog/real-world-data-noaa-climate-data

I wouldn't recommend doing joins on a MV - the hash table needs to be built for all insert blocks. This is going to dramatically slow down inserts.
You should try to use a dictionary or Engine=JOIN table - the latter will ensure the hash table is pre-built in memory. For your usecase you can use a polygon dictionary to hold your zone data (depends on size and example https://clickhouse.com/blog/real-world-data-noaa-climate-data)
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries#polygon-dictionaries
Note this join will only be triggered for inserts into source1.
If you must do what you are doing include 'SETTINGS allow_experimental_join_condition = 1' in your MV query.

thanks, I will try your suggestions, 40 zones for now. For mvp dictionary I guess is ok in my case.

polygon dictionary is perfect for this.

Can you give advice on how to design this pipeline when there will be geospatial cells instead of regions, like S2, so there will be a lot of them?

You would want to do s2CellsIntersect calls i assume against the cells at insert time with the point from source1?

yeah something like this, may be it would be better to do outside of clickhouse with some other tool, I don't know yet. So I got point in input, and should match it with some cell id, to do count grouping by cell id later with queries.

Right now there is no dictionary which offers intersection of S2 or H3. You could use a standard dictionary so the data is in memory and join against this like in your original query. Your mileage will very.
